# ERC-721: How to determine which Tokens an Address Own

Tags: ethereum

If you are using the ERC-721 standard, what is the prefer method determining which tokens the address owns in a DAPP.

Currently I'm request all the Transfer Events for an address and basically sorting them into transfer in and transfer out, and then using that to determine which tokens the user owns.

Is there a simpler way I missed.

Answer (score -1):

`Transfer` events may be emitted also by contracts that are not ERC-721 tokens, or some noname tokens that you might not be interested in.

The actual token ownership is stored in the tokens contracts (and not the DAPP contract).

So your current approach is pretty much as straightforward as it can get, if you want to automatically keep track of **all** tokens that the address currently owns (and some false positives as well).

*Note: This is also similar to the approach of Etherscan, which listens to all `Transfer` event logs and if the sender contract is listed in their database of tokens, they use the event log data to update balances of the sender and recipient.*

---

If you're willing/able to create and maintain a list of tokens that you want to follow, I'd recommend a simpler approach:

1. Define the list of followed token contract addresses (e.g. [ECF](https://etherscan.io/address/0x97ca7fe0b0288f5eb85f386fed876618fb9b8ab8#code) or [RARI](https://etherscan.io/address/0x60f80121c31a0d46b5279700f9df786054aa5ee5#code))
2. For each of these token contracts, call `balanceOf(<your_dapp_address>)` that returns amount of tokens that the `<your_dapp_address>` currently owns.

Comment: This will obviously answer "how many" and not "which" tokens...